# What is the name of spring-webmvc on Spring Enterprise Bundle Repository?

Tags: spring, maven

Are `spring-webmvc` on Maven and `org.springframework.web.servlet` on EBR the same? I can't seem to find `spring-webmvc` on Spring's EBR.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Spring EBR:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#dependency-management), the bundle's  symbolic name is derived from the main package root, e.g. `org.springframework.beans` or `org.springframework.web.servlet`. Since one of the core classes of Spring MVC, i.e. `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`, sits in the `org.springframework.web.servlet` package, the bundle is named `org.springframework.web.servlet`.

Comment: Do you know what is the state of Spring EBR and its replacement Eclipse EBR?